# Modifying Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT
    PATNO,
    SUM([AMT]) as AMT,
    Dr.[DRG_Rate],
    drg,
    CASE WHEN SUM([AMT]) > 275000 THEN ((SUM([AMT]) -275000) *.195) + DR.[DRG_Rate] ELSE 0 END AS StopLoss,
    CASE WHEN SUM([AMT]) > 275000 THEN ((SUM([AMT]) -275000) *.195) + DR.[DRG_Rate] ELSE DR.[DRG_Rate] END AS ClaimTotal
FROM
    [dataMain] AS RD
    INNER JOIN [drg] AS DR ON RD.DRG = DR.[DRG_Code]
GROUP BY
    PATNO,
    [DRG_Rate],
    drg
```

Code is working but I need to add a CASE stating:
If Qty > High Trim then the output of  QTY-High Trim * Per Diem High Trim Outlier should be added to the claim total. The claims are unique to their patient number, and there is only one drg code per claim.

**Important to note that QTY is defined as the line item corresponding to any RevCode between 100-164. So for my example, QTY is 60 for patient 555 because there is a line item with Rev code 110 with that QTY.**

My Input:

**Table 1: [dataMain]**

| **PNAME** | **HSSVC** | **ISDDATE** | **DNAME** | **INSNME** | **ORGBL** | **DRG** | **RevCode** | **CPTCDA** | **QTY** | **DESCRIPTION** | **AMT** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | XX | SIP | 43532 | YY | ZZ | 59705.11 | 3 | 110 | NULL | 60 | ergrgeqw |
| 555 | XX | SIP | 43532 | YY | ZZ | 59705.11 | 3 | 258 | J7120 | 54 | wrth |
| 555 | XX | SIP | 43532 | YY | ZZ | 59705.11 | 3 | 636 | J3370 | 21 | ffff |
| 777 | XX | SIP | 43532 | YY | ZZ | 59705.11 | 4 | 115 | J3370 | 2 | ffgggg |
| 777 | XX | SIP | 43532 | YY | ZZ | 59705.11 | 4 | 636 | J3370 | 2 | eqtaghagh |

**Table 2: [drg]**

| **Description** | **DRG Weight** | **ALOS** | **High Trim** | **Effective Date** | **DRG Rate** | **Per Diem High Trim Outlier** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ECMO OR TRACH W MV >96 HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ O.R. | 18.2974 | 30 | 54 | 00:00.0 | 467 |
| 4 | TRACH W MV >96 HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W/O MAJ O.R. | 11.4192 | 24 | 40 | 00:00.0 | 750 |

INSERT Statements:

For main table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dataMain](
   PATNO       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PNAME       VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,HSSVC       VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,ISDDATE     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,DNAME       VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,INSNME      VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,ORGBL       NUMERIC(8,2) NOT NULL
  ,DRG         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,RevCode     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,CPTCDA      VARCHAR(5)
  ,QTY         INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(44) NOT NULL
  ,AMT         NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO [dataMain](PATNO,PNAME,HSSVC,ISDDATE,DNAME,INSNME,ORGBL,DRG,RevCode,CPTCDA,QTY,DESCRIPTION,AMT) VALUES (555,'XX','SIP',43532,'YY','ZZ',59705.11,3,110,NULL,60,'ergrgeqw',1604.14);
INSERT INTO [dataMain](PATNO,PNAME,HSSVC,ISDDATE,DNAME,INSNME,ORGBL,DRG,RevCode,CPTCDA,QTY,DESCRIPTION,AMT) VALUES (555,'XX','SIP',43532,'YY','ZZ',59705.11,3,258,'J7120',54,'wrth',78.75);
INSERT INTO [dataMain](PATNO,PNAME,HSSVC,ISDDATE,DNAME,INSNME,ORGBL,DRG,RevCode,CPTCDA,QTY,DESCRIPTION,AMT) VALUES (555,'XX','SIP',43532,'YY','ZZ',59705.11,3,636,'J3370',21,'ffff',77.76);
INSERT INTO [dataMain](PATNO,PNAME,HSSVC,ISDDATE,DNAME,INSNME,ORGBL,DRG,RevCode,CPTCDA,QTY,DESCRIPTION,AMT) VALUES (777,'XX','SIP',43532,'YY','ZZ',59705.11,4,115,'J3370',2,'ffgggg',55);
INSERT INTO [dataMain](PATNO,PNAME,HSSVC,ISDDATE,DNAME,INSNME,ORGBL,DRG,RevCode,CPTCDA,QTY,DESCRIPTION,AMT) VALUES (777,'XX','SIP',43532,'YY','ZZ',59705.11,4,636,'J3370',2,'eqtaghagh',55);
```

For DRG Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [drg](
   DRG_Code                   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Description                VARCHAR(67) NOT NULL
  ,DRG_Weight                 NUMERIC(7,4) NOT NULL
  ,ALOS                       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,High_Trim                  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Effective_Date             VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,DRG_Rate                   NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL
  ,Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier NUMERIC(7,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO [drg](DRG_Code,Description,DRG_Weight,ALOS,High_Trim,Effective_Date,DRG_Rate,Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier) VALUES (3,'ECMO OR TRACH W MV >96 HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W MAJ O.R.',18.2974,30,54,'00:00.0',235121.59,5486.17);
INSERT INTO [drg](DRG_Code,Description,DRG_Weight,ALOS,High_Trim,Effective_Date,DRG_Rate,Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier) VALUES (4,'TRACH W MV >96 HRS OR PDX EXC FACE, MOUTH & NECK W/O MAJ O.R.',11.4192,24,40,'00:00.0',146736.72,4279.82);
```

Desired Output for the Sample Data Given:

| **AMT** | **DRG Rate** | **DRG** | **STOP LOSS** | **Claim Total** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 555 | 1760.65 | 467 | 3 | 0 |
| 777 | 110 | 750 | 4 | 0 |

*Notes about output:

1. There is only ONE claim per patient.
2. There is only ONE DRG code per patient
3. For patient 555, note that because QTY>High Trim on the DRG table, I calculated it as (60-54)*5486.17 + DRG_Rate for DRG 3. The 5486.17 is the per diem outlier for drg 3. On the other hand, patient 777 doesn't meet that condition so it's just an easy lookup for the drg rate. This formula needs to apply for every claim.
4. The AMT column is the SUM of all the AMT line items for the patient

Please let me know if you need additional info or clarification.
Thanks!

Comment: That is `CASE` **expressions**; it returns a scalar value. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, and the 2 operate very differently.

Comment: Markdown shows perfectly when I edit, but it's cut off the first column for my tables...fixing

Comment: Larnu, so are you saying a CASE statement is not the best way to achieve what I am looking for? I think I agree with that...

Comment: I'm saying that `CASE` **statements** don't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: you code throws errors, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4cc7c1af5ff106497c625170414dcf73)   `Msg 207 Level 16 State 1 Line 10
Invalid column name 'DRG Code'.
Msg 207 Level 16 State 1 Line 13
Invalid column name 'DRG Rate'.`

Comment: Fixed code Luuk, sorry

Comment: Regarding your *Notes about output , point 3. How did you decide on 60 for patient 555. I see that patient has 54 and 21 as well for qty for drug 3? Also, your tables in the question doesn't match the inserts that you have provided.

Comment: @RaseenaAbdul they do match, I just have issues w/ markdown. In edit mode all my tables show perfectly but when I submit everything goes off. I decided on 60 because as in the insert statement, you can see patient 555 has a rev code line of 110 and the QTY for that line is 60, so I use that QTY for my calculation